# time complexity of permutations of a string (Cracking the Coding Interview, Chapter VI - Example 12)

Tags: java, string, time-complexity, permutation, complexity-theory

There are already other questions on this example from the book, but none of them have left me satisfied/answer the question in detail in my opinion.

I'm wondering about the time complexity of the code below.

```
public static void permutation(String str) {
    permutation(str, "");
}

public static void permutation(String str, String prefix) {
    if (str.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println(prefix);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            String rem = str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i + 1);
            permutation(rem, prefix + str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

SUMMARY: My main question is just how you take the for loop into account when finding the time complexity of the code above. There are 3 different approaches to the problem I mention below and I don't understand the role of the for loop in the first two and am not sure if the 3rd approach which I came up with is correct.

The book estimates the complexity like this:

There are n! permutations of a string, so the base case is called n! times.

The depth of the recursive tree is of length n, so the total number of nodes is bounded above by n! * n

The base case is O(n)--it just prints every character of the string.

The else case is O(n) because of the string concatenation.

Therefore, each node is O(n) work.

So, O(n! * n * n) whic his O(n^2 * n!) is a runtime upper bound.

First, if someone could clarify for me, the reason that the string concatentation is O(n) is because the string rem you define plus prefix + str.charAt(i) will sum to n?

Moving on, the reason the explanation above confuses me is that it seems to ignore the for loop in the else case? I think the amount of work each node does is n/2 * n, because on average the loop runs n / 2 times and has O(n) work inside it. This leads to an upper bound of O(n^2 * n * n!) which is O(n^3 * n!). So, why does the book seemingly ignore the loop? Am I taking it into account correctly?

The question/answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858886/counting-all-permutations-of-a-string-cracking-the-coding-interview-chapter-vi) post take a more detailed approach to get a tighter runtime which still leave me confused. All of the top answers work make sense to me until "The total number of iterations is: 3 + 6 + 6 = 15. This is about the same as number of nodes in the tree. So the average number of iterations for each node is constant." I don't understand this sentence and was hoping somebody could explain better how you add in the loop iterations to study the runtime? I'm not sure how the number of iterations for each node is constant as it depends on the current length of the string.

Final part of my question is whether this is a valid approach: Here's how I would approach the problem: there are [image] recursive nodes, as the linked answer above claims. In the first recursive layer, the loop runs n times and then the substring work also depends on n, so we have n!/n! (for the 1 node only) * n * n. In the second layer with n nodes, the substring work is the same but the loop runs n - 1 times. So we have n!/(n-1)! * (n-1) * n. Continuing this pattern and summing together, we end up with:
n!/n! * n * n + n!/(n-1)! * (n-1) * n + n!/(n-2)! * (n-2) * n + ... + n!/(n-(n-1))! * (1) * n + n! * n (the last term goes into the if case which has no loop). 
Is this analysis correct? If so, plugging into wolfram gives [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28n%21%2F%28n-i%29%21%20*%20%28n-i%29%20*%20n%29%20from%20i%20%3D%200%20to%20n%20-%201) resultwhich seems to be O(n * n!) if I'm understanding it right? I don't really know the gamma function so this could easily be wrong. I was initially thinking the sum would equal something giving O(n * n!) because the denominators of the first part of each term would cancel with number from the number of loop iterations.